# Symmetric matrix and Hermitian matrix, unitarily diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is an n by n real matrix, then $A$ is Hermitian if and only if $A$ is symmetric.

Is this statement true or false? I think it is true?

Second question: Is every real symmetric matrix unitarily diagonalizable?
This is false right?   I want see some explanation, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the definitions of Hermitian and Symmetric to the first question?

Answer (score 0):

Yesi you are right. For second question, I don't know what do you mean by unitarily diagonalizable. Real symmetric matrices are diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: if $A$ is a real matrix, then it is Hermitian if and only if it is symmetric.

Similarly, if $U$ is a real matrix, then it is unitary if and only if it is orthogonal. With that said, it is indeed true that a real symmetric matrix is unitarily diagonalizable. The spectral theorem for symmetric matrices that $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable, i.e. there exists a real diagonal matrix $D$ and an *orthogonal* matrix $U$ for which $A = UDU^{-1}$. Since $U$ is real and orthogonal, it follows that $U$ is *unitary*, which means that $A$ is also *unitarily* diagonalizable.